# Residues at poles

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

What is the residue of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^a}$$ at $x^2=\pm i$, where $0<a<1$ ? My intuition tells me that there must be a non-zero residue, but my attempts to compute tells me the residue is $0$. How can this be so when $x^2+1=0$ when $x=\pm i$ ?

Comment: What makes you think this is a well-defined meromorphic function in a neighborhood of $\pm i$? I.e., are these really poles?

Comment: $f(x)$ is not meromorphic at $x=\pm i$, these are branch points.

Comment: Cauchy defined residue as the integral along an infinitesimally small circle around the point. In modern words the limit as that circle's radius tends to zero. The question makes sense even if it is not a pole. Now, a branch of the function may have to be fixed and the answer may be that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @TedShifrin So because the function is multi-valued in a neighbourhood of the point $z=\pm i$ then the function is not meromorphic since there exist an infinite number of points about which $f$ is not holomorphic (i.e. we have discontinuity along the entire branch cut)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although $(1+z^2)^a$ is not analytic in a neighborhood of $i$ or $-i$, we can still compute the circular integral around each point missing the branch cut.

$\log(1+z^2)$ can be well-defined in a domain cut so that if a closed path circled $i$, it also circles $-i$. For example, we could have a branch cut that connects $i$ and $-i$ or a branch cut that extends from $i$ to $\infty$ and another cut that extends from $-i$ to $\infty$.

On any such domain we can then define $(1+z^2)^{\large a}$ via the exponential function. In any case, near $i$,
$$
|f(z)|\sim2^{\large-a}|z-i|^{\large-a}
$$
On a small circle of radius $r$, the length of a circular path is $2\pi r$ and the value of the function would be $\sim2^{\large-a}r^{\large-a}$ the integral around the circle would be at most $\sim2^{\large-a}r^{1\large-a}\to0$ if $0\lt a\lt1$.

Thus, even though we cannot form a closed circuit around $i$ because of branch cuts, the integral around the point vanishes as the radius goes to $0$.

**Caveat:** Although we have a $0$ "residue" at $i$ and $-i$, this cannot be extended to any useful contour. To extend the result for the small circle to a larger path, the paths are usually connected by two superimposed connectors oppositely directed that cancel each other. Here, the connectors would have to follow the branch cut and the function is not continuous across the branch cut so the integrals would not necessarily cancel.

For example, consider $f(z)=z^{1/2}$ with a branch cut along the positive real axis.

$\hspace{3.2cm}$[image]

Limiting to the real axis from above, $f(z)\to\sqrt{x}$, the normal positive square root.
Limiting to the real axis from below, $f(z)\to-\sqrt{x}$, the negative square root.

Let's try to use the same construction to show that the integral along two contours that circle the same singularities are the same. The only place to add the connectors, and keep the contour inside the domain of definition of $f$, is on each side of the branch cut. However, the integral along the connectors do not cancel; in fact, they actually reinforce.

The integral counterclockwise around a circle of radius $r$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}\,\mathrm{d}re^{i\theta}
&=\int_0^{2\pi}r^{3/2}ie^{i3\theta/2}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\left.\frac23r^{3/2}e^{i3\theta/2}\right]_0^{2\pi}\\
&=-\frac43r^{3/2}
\end{align}
$$
This makes sense. As shown above, the integral along the circle as $r\to0$ is $0$. The integral along each of the connectors is
$$
\int_0^r\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_r^0-\sqrt{x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac23r^{3/2}
$$
So the total along all the contours is $0$. However, the point is that the integral along the circles is not constant since the integrals along the connectors do not cancel.

Comment: You can make a closed circuit around $i$. The only issue may be that the function is not holomorphic along all of the path. This is of course not a problem to ask for the residue of it. I say this, just to make precise what you mean by not being able to form a closed circuit around $i$.

Comment: @RGB: We would like the contour to lie within the domain of definition of the function, and the function is not defined on the branch cut. Therefore, I would say that we cannot make a closed circuit close to $i$ or $-i$.

Comment: Together with the arbitrary definition of the function, by choosing a branch cut, you can define the function along the cut by taking the limits, say from 'above' the cut or just any other values. The integral is not going to care much. The definition of residue doesn't even need those connectors (which by the way can also lie away from the cut and they will always cancel since it is the same integral travelled backwards). The only important thing is that the function is not holomorphic. But that is only important if one is going to use it in the computation.

Comment: The role of the 'connectors' is to create an auxiliary path along which we can use Cauchy's theorem. The problem is not that the integrals along the connectors are not going to cancel, they always will by definition. You can also put the 'connectors' outside the branch cut. The problem is that there is no way to get an auxiliary path along which Cauchy's theorem holds.

Comment: Maybe it is a question of language. What do you mean by "circuit"? I am assuming it is just a closed path with the function being almost everywhere defined on it as a measurable function. That is all is needed to define the integral and then take limit afterwards.

Comment: @RGB: I have attempted to describe my concerns a bit clearer in my **Caveat** above.

Comment: It should be clear now for the reader what you mean. On the other hand what I am saying is: In the figure, the integral on the circuit is an integral of a function on a Riemann surface, but not a function on the plane. If we define a function a function *on the plane* by, say choosing the value $\sqrt{x}$ on the branch-cut. The integral along the connectors do cancel as it is the same integral in opposite direction. The problem this times is that along the big annular circuit it is not zero because the function is not holomorphic where it needs to be to apply Cauchy's.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem. Firstly, sorry for writing my trouble to you here as a comment. My rights to ask run out. I have a right to ask 50 questions per a month. I am a student. And I am studying by myself on summer holiday. I need to ask questions here. How to gain my rights to ask a question here? Please help me. I promise, after august,2 I Will never ask a question here. But I need until august, 2. Hopefully, you can find a solution. Best regards.. @robjohn

Comment: @B11b: I'm not sure what can be done about this. I know that moderators have no control over the rate limiting feature of the site, nor do I think the community managers do either. If you have a pressing question, you can ask in chat, but don't pester people or ask over and over. See the [Etiquette Rules](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3890).